# Cannot omit 'new' keyword despite using Dart 2.0

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-2

When i run the tests of my application i get this exception:

```
NoSuchMethodError: Attempted to use type 'SimplePipe' as a function. Since types do not define a method 'call', this is not possible. Did you intend to call the SimplePipe constructor and forget the 'new' operator?
```

I conclude from this error message that my project is actually not using Dart 2.0 but Dart 1.0. 
The sdk is set to `>=2.0.0-dev.53.0 <2.0.0` in `pubspec.yaml`, though.

A friend of mine is getting this this error message when running the same tests under the same conditions on his PC. He already tried running `pub get`.

```
Dart 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58 is incompatible with your dependencies' SDK constraints. Please run "pub get" again
```

**`pubspec.yaml`:**

```
name: timecoder_common
description: A Dart Libary containin all the shared logic
version: 0.0.1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.53.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  uuid: "^0.5.3"
  json_annotation: "^0.2.3"
  http: "^0.11.3"
  rxdart: "^0.16.6"
  test: "^0.12.34"

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: "^0.8.0"
  json_serializable: "^0.5.0"
```

Comment: How are you attempting to run it? If it's through the VM you likely need `--preview-dart-2`. If you're using `pub run` it should be `DART_VM_OPTIONS=--preview-dart-2 pub run test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dart 2.0 SDK does not enable this by default (yet).

For Flutter, you will [need to be on the latest SDK](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-beta-3-7d88125245dc):

> In this blog post, we’ll take a deeper look at the specific improvements we’ve made in Beta 3 itself.

For the command-line VM, as mentioned in the comments, you must opt-in:

```
dart --preview-dart-2 bin/main.dart
```

Comment: His error message is using `SimplePipe` which is an angular feature.

Comment: `SimplePipe` is a custom class built upon rxdart Observables and is not dependant any angular_dart or flutter lib.